# Horizontal scrolling with inline-block working in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have implemented horizontal scrolling in Firefox, but it's not working in Chrome. In Firefox I have this situation (where A, B, C, D are divs):

[image: Firefox]

but when accessing the same page with Chrome, this is what I see:

[image: Chrome]

the divs are structured like this:

```
<div class="news-list-container">
    <div class="news-list-item">A</div>
    <div class="news-list-item">B</div>
    <div class="news-list-item">C</div>
    <div class="news-list-item">D</div>
    <div class="news-list-item">E</div>
    <div class="news-list-item">F</div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.news-list-container {
    display: inline-block;
    display: -moz-inline-box;
    height: 187px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: 700px;
}

.news-list-item {
    border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    float: left;
    height: 175px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 184px;
}
```

Apparently, Chrome is not recognizing the display: inline-block. Is there something similar/equivalent to -moz-inline-block that does the same for Chrome? If not, how can I obtain the same horizontal scrolling on the two browsers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ / http://jsbin.com/ demo that shows the problem?

Comment: Already solved the problem, but thanks for your interest in helping me with it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it after some experimenting. I had to add another div in between and set its width to the total width of the contained elements (considering borders and paddings). This way the *display* property is no longer needed and everything works in both Firefox and Chrome.

```
<div class="news-list-container">
  <div id=container>
    <div class="news-list-item">A</div>
    <div class="news-list-item">B</div>
    <div class="news-list-item">C</div>
    <div class="news-list-item">D</div>
    <div class="news-list-item">E</div>
    <div class="news-list-item">F</div>
  </div>
</div>

.news-list-container {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

#container {
    height: 187px;
    width: 1176px;
}

.news-list-item {
    border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    float: left;
    height: 175px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 184px;
}
```

Comment: To avoid adding an extra `div` with the correct width, I'd have done it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/NTKK3/.

Comment: @thirtydot try adding more text to the divs.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui: Fair point, but it's easy to fix: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/NTKK3/68/

Answer (score 1):

USE Below CSS Property .

`-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden`