# CSS Inline-Block Scroll side ways

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to use CSS to make this code work in any horizontal measure. Like [Horizontal Scrolling with Inline Block Working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209367/horizontal-scrolling-with-inline-block-working-in-firefox-but-not-in-chrome#), i've been unsucessful.

My code is ready and gives me the visuals i want, but when we zoom the page or use it in a smaller horizontal size, instead of adding a horizontal scroll bar, it breaks down.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Gantt Display</title>
<style>
    body {font-family:Verdana;font-size:10px;}
    .gantt {overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden;background-color:#ffffff;font-size:0;}
    .gantt .head {display:block;}
    .gantt .head .text {height:32px;display:block;text-align:center;font-weight:bold;background-color:#eeeeee;vertical-align:middle;font-size:10px;}
    .gantt .head .month {display:inline-block;border-bottom:1px solid #eeeeee;}
    .gantt .head .day {display:inline-block;width:32px;height:32px;text-align:center;background-color:#f8f8f8;margin:0;padding:0;vertical-align:middle;font-size:10px;}
    .gantt .head .weekend {display:inline-block;width:32px;height:32px;text-align:center;background-color:#eeeeee;margin:0;padding:0;vertical-align:middle;font-size:10px;}
    .gantt .chart {display:block;}
    .gantt .chart .day {display:inline-block;width:32px;text-align:center;min-height:256px;background-color:#f8f8f8;margin:0;padding:0;}
    .gantt .chart .weekend {display:inline-block;width:32px;text-align:center;min-height:256px;background-color:#eeeeee;margin:0;padding:0;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="gantt">
    <div class="head">
        <div class="month">
            <div class="text">Setembro</div>
            <div class="day">19</div>
            <div class="day">20</div>
            <div class="day">21</div>
            <div class="day">22</div>
            <div class="day">23</div>
            <div class="weekend">S</div>
            <div class="weekend">D</div>
            <div class="day">26</div>
            <div class="day">27</div>
            <div class="day">28</div>
            <div class="day">29</div>
            <div class="day">30</div>
        </div>
        <div class="month">
            <div class="text">Outubro</div>
            <div class="weekend">S</div>
            <div class="weekend">D</div>
            <div class="day">3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="chart">
        <div class="day"></div>
        <div class="day"></div>
        <div class="day"></div>
        <div class="day"></div>
        <div class="day"></div>
        <div class="weekend"></div>
        <div class="weekend"></div>
        <div class="day"></div>
        <div class="day"></div>
        <div class="day"></div>
        <div class="day"></div>
        <div class="day"></div>
        <div class="weekend"></div>
        <div class="weekend"></div>
        <div class="day"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDITED THIS: answered!**
And also, i'd like to understand why are spaces between the "vertical day bars" if "margin" and "padding" are both set to zero?

**EDITED: Show the print screens of the problem**
That code, that's almost as i want, leaves me with this "resize" problem:

Correct Page (when the page width allows the hole page to be displayed)
[image: correct page]

Deformed Page (when ... not)
[image: deformed page]

Comment: The spaces between the vertical bars is because you're treating those DIVs as inline elements with `display: inline-block;`. Any space in the markup between the elements will be treated like the space between text in the markup. You don't need to assign `display: block;` to a `<div>`. It already has block level formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spaces that you asked, will answer your question. That spaces are totally normal, because `inline-block` means inline and block at the same time. Inline elements will follow the text line, and one space in the code is one space in the rendered document. That spaces occupy the size of the font-size. To solve the whole problem I suggest this:

```
.gantt { font-size: 0; }
.gantt .day, 
.gantt .weekend { font-size: 1rem; }
```

By this way you remove all spaces between boxes and reset the font-size on days and weekend days. And that's all!

### EDIT: Problem resizing

The problem of the resize is that the container is smaller than the content. You have two options:

1) Set a width to the container (32px * total cells + margin)
2) Set a property on the container that avoids to line breaking (`white-space: nowrap`)

So change your code with:

```
.gantt { 
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: i understand, it actualy resolved but i used "10px" instead "1rem" - since it was too big. The line-breaking though did not resolve

Comment: any clue on the "inline-block" part? i need to align properly side-by-side, but if i have too many columns (days), it breaks down (see images i added)

Comment: @SammuelMiranda edited with two solutions for line breaking. Are you Galician? Me too :D

Comment: No, not Galician Marcos, Brazilian. and above you edited saying "You Have Two options", but placed only one ... rsrs

Comment: Ok! Brazilian shares the portuguese language that was the same as Galician in the past. When I see your screenshots I see `setembro` and `outubro`, that's the same of my language. However, this is solved. See you soon!

Comment: Hehehe ... yes, ok; your help made all the diference my friend, thank you very much - i keep writing in english because you never know who will be reading, and english is more ... scattered around the world.

Comment: Yeah, here we need to talk in english. However, there are specified language versions of stackoverflow, for example in spanish: http://es.stackoverflow.com . Good luck!